# How do you make Jackson use Kotlin default params for missing values?

Tags: json, jackson, kotlin

I've a Kotlin data class that looks like this,

```
data class SomeData(
   private val notInJson: String = "some default value",
   private val inJson: String
)
```

and a json string, I wish to deserialize into an instance of this class -

```
{
    "inJson" : "value"
}
```

When I try to deserialize this data, I get an error that the parameter `notInJson` cannot be null. Seems like Jackson is passing a null value for it since it's missing in the json string.

Is there a way to have Jackson not pass in any value for it, so that the default specified in the class definition could be used?

--EDIT--

I do register a KotlinModule() with the mapper. Using version 2.7.8 or all jackson packages involved.

The following code -

```
@Test fun jackson_kotlin_module() {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
    println(
        mapper.readValue("""{ "inJson" : "some value" }""",     SomeData::class.java))
}
```

gives me -

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple 
type, class SomeData] value failed (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException): 
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method SomeData.<init>, parameter 
notInJson
at [Source: { "inJson" : "some value" }; line: 1, column: 27]
```

Comment: as @miensol says, you need to upgrade to newest Jackson (2.8.4 or higher) since the ability to handle default parameters was added then and has not been backported.

Comment: I was stuck on this for a while - apparently you need to enable the `KotlinFeature.NullIsSameAsDefault` feature on the KotlinModule as well - see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/130

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Default params is a Kotlin feature. Jackson does not know about it hence we need to inform it somehow to be able to support it. Thankfully there's the excellent [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) which let's you do:

```
val mapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(KotlinModule()) //let Jackson know about Kotlin
...
data class SomeData(
    private val notInJson: String = "some default value",
    private val inJson: String
)
...
val data = mapper.readValue<SomeData>("""{"inJson": "sample value"}""")
println(data) // -> SomeData(notInJson=some default value, inJson=sample value)
```

For instructions how to use it take a look at [jackson-module-kotlin Readme](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) and **pay special attention to versions** of the module and Jackson itself. In order for the default parameters to work you need [at least version `2.8.4`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin#status) of [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin)

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned I am already using the KotlinModule(). Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @PuneetArora You need to pay attention to versions. jackson-kotlin-module 2.8.4 supports default parameters on constructor and creator methods.

Comment: Best solution, I think it can be answer

Comment: `KotlinModule` is now deprecated. Use `ÒbjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()` from jackson-module-kotlin's `ExtenstionsKt`.